# npx react-native run-android on mac m1 Unsuccessful

Tags: react-native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'testRn'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find lint-model-30.0.4.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:30.0.4).

BUILD FAILED in 1s

```
at makeError (/Users/rimaj/Desktop/testRn/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
at /Users/rimaj/Desktop/testRn/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/rimaj/Desktop/testRn/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (/Users/rimaj/Desktop/testRn/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is the node module `@react-native-community/cli-platform-android` that is not working.

You should verify that's the module is up to date and correctly installed.